# WP plugin: Inserting block of HTML

Tags: wordpress

How can I insert a block of HTML from a WP plugin?

For example, I was thinking of something like:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'myFunc' ));
//...
//...
//...
//...
public function myFunc() {
           echo '<p>I am HTML code!</p>';          
        }
```

The problem with that is that wp_footer, according to WP documentation, might not be available on some themes (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer).

Anything else that I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can manually add `get_footer()` to your theme files if it isn't included by default.  According to WP's reference this method is widely supported in themes so it's safe to assume it'll work for most.  If you absolutely want to code for the edge cases you can register a widget and then have it print out in the footer section of your theme.

In your plugin's [init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) function you can add:

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget(
   'footerMessage',        // your unique widget id
   'Footer Message',          // widget name
   'myFunc',  // callback function
   array(                  // options
       'description' => 'Displays footer message.'
   )
);
```

With this item included all you'll need to do is add your widget to your theme.

In your theme folder you will most likely have a `footer.php`, if not you can add this call to a standard page template:

```
<?php the_widget('footerMessage'); ?>
```

This will print out the widget exactly where you want it in the template and will be completely theme agnostic.